# Cypress.on after all tests in file have finished running

Tags: cypress

I have an `it` clause that runs 10 times, with this in it:

```js
Cypress.on('test:after:run', test => {
    addContext(
      { test },
      {
        title: '...',
        value: {
```

The above gets executes for every one of the 10 iterations.
Is there any way to make it execute only for the last iteration, or - after all iteration are done?

(I tried putting it in an `after()` clause but the `addContext()` function doesn't work then).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to do would be to only run the code on a certain test

```js
Cypress.on('test:after:run', test => {
  if (test.fullTitle() === 'This is the tenth test') {
    addContext(...
```

---

Or to eliminate the hard coded test name get creative with the test properties

(this depends on the nesting of your test suite - the `describe()` blocks)

```js
Cypress.on('test:after:run', test => {
  const suite = cy.state('test').parent
  if (suite.tests.slice(-1) === test.fullTitle()) {
    addContext(...
```

---

or fire just **once** inside the last test **only**

```js
it('This is the tenth test', () => {
  Cypress.once('test:after:run', test => {
    addContext(...
```

---

or in `after()` hook

```js
after(() => {
  const test = cy.state('test')
  addContext(...
```

---

or at the end of the spec

(need more details to be exact)

**cypress.config.js**

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('after:spec', (spec, results) => {
        addContext(...
      })
    },
  },
})
```